# Why is collector-emitter breakdown voltage (open base) lower than the collector-base breakdown voltage (open emitter)?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I need to understand why the collector base breakdown voltage is greater than collector emitter breakdown voltage. Can it be analyzed from the energy band diagram so as to remember it mnemotechnically?. Most of the sources analyze it from a mathematical point of view only, I need to understand the mechanism so to remember it intuitively.

From what I understand in a NPN transistor, the base emitter junction potential, when Vce is applied, it opposes the base emitter depletion zone electric field, essentially "pushing" the electrons from the emitter to the base making the base a N-type material temporarily. Since the base is now full of minority carriers, and the collector base junction is reverse biased, and with sufficient thermal energy an electron could enter the great collector base reverse biased junctions electric field and be accelerated with sufficient energy, avalanche breakdown happens.

For the Collector base junction breakdown, its just like a reverse biased diode junction, there will be a point where thermally generated minority carriers will be accelerated and produce avalanche breakdown.
[image: energy band diagram showing valence and conduction levels]

So both mechanisms for breakdown are identical, avalanche is caused by collision ionization.

Now my answer would be, the collector emitter breakdown voltage is smaller due to the greater concentration of minority carriers in the base collector junction with the open base. More carriers, greater probability of collision ionization, therefore avalanche. It would be analogous to increasing the temperature. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about the emitter-base breakdown being an avalanche process -- at least with the small-signal transistors that I'm used to designing with, it's usually around 6V -- as far as I understand that indicates a mix of Zener and avalanche breakdown.

Comment: I always thought it was because with an open base, the transistor's current gain multiplies the avalanche current.

Comment: That would be the engineering answer, current gain isnt a physical parameter, strictly speaking. The current injected into the base is nothing more than the statistical effect of having too many energy levels available at the base and too many carriers on the emitter side. When the emitter-colector circuit closes, the carriers have lower energy levels available so as to be there, just like any object will get attracted to earth by gravity, if there is space for it to go lower, it will. But I am also not sure if the Colector emitter breakdown is an avalanche phenomenon.

Comment: @GustavoHenriqueFossNeves Of course it's a physical answer. Current gain is a physical phenomenon, measurable with physical instruments. Abstract theory is more remote from the physical world.

Comment: @JohnDoty What I meant is that it doesnt explain the mechanism, which is what im interested in.

Comment: @GustavoHenriqueFossNeves It's the same mechanism as usual transistor action, except that the extra positive base charge comes from the collector rather than from the base.

Comment: @JohnDoty thanks for taking the time but you are not being helpful. What is the definitive answer for BVce being lower than BVcb?